# Sonata Admin Bundle: CRUD templates are just simple tables?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I'm working with the Sonata Admin Bundle (Symphony 2.8) and I'd like to have the CRUD templates look like in the screenshot. It seems like it's a common thing which is already shipped with sonata but everytime I run the CRUD command (app/console generate:doctrine:crud) my crud templates consist of simple html tables.

From what I understand is that you can create custom templates but as every other Sonata Admin List view looks exactly as in the screenshot, I assume that I need to activate something in the config first?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong command, for sonata admin crud you use `app/console sonata:admin:generate`.

you can find a list of sonata command here:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/console.html

Comment: Mhm okay, looks like I was heading in the wrong direction, thank you. Could you give me a hint on why/how to create the crud files afterwards? Because everything it did was creating an admin file of my entity and the service-config

Comment: @Saerdn that is the crud file, go to your `admin/dashboard` and you should see new item in your sidebar

Comment: I still had a custom admin navigation/dashboard active, that's why it didn't show up at first. Thank you.

Comment: @Saerdn glad to help